# Visual Studio performance and add-ins

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, add-in

Do the useful add-ins (Resharper, StyleCop, etc.) to Visual Studio speed up your work? Or tools need too many resources and you have to wait until each add-in completes execution?

[Update]: By the way does some body notice whether performance of IDE + Resharper is better for solutions that contain web sites or web applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use some add-ins as long as they don't affect the performance of Visual Studio. To that end, tools like StyleCop, MZ-Tools, and Visual Studio Commands are the clear winners.

The problem I have with tools like Refactor! and Resharper are that

1. They degrade performance, particularly for large solutions.
2. You become dependent on the shortcut keys, etc. they provide and become completely useless when working on another environment that doesn't have them installed.

Yes, tools like Refactor! and Resharper are excellent for what they do and can increase your typing productivity but I don't think the gain is worth the dependence. This, of course, depends largely on how you use them. For things like refactoring method parameters, changing fields into properties, etc. they can be very useful and potentially save a lot of time. Again, while it can save a lot of time it is still important to know what these tools are actually doing for you so you can still be productive without them.

Comment: Its true, I turn on Resharper only for implementation new functionality or serious refactoring of existing code. But when you are debugging and open an old class that has a 200 Resharper warnings you simply cannot type!

Comment: You've got a good point there... if you're used to the benefits of something like ReSharper, yout might find yourself less productive when it's not available.  Of course, the same could be said for Visual Studio.... Hrm... I suggest we all use Notepad!

Comment: @kyoryu: Visual Studio is really a "lowest common denominator" thing, anyone writing .NET code should be familiar with what it provides and how to work within it while tools like R# and Refactor aren't always going to be available. That being said, I do feel that things like IntelliSense are great but have the same effect. I've interviewed plenty of people that didn't know what basic functions were available on the string or DateTime class if they weren't sitting in front of VS looking at the IntelliSense list (and these were people claiming to be senior/seasoned developers.)

Answer (score 7):

I can speak very strongly that resharper definitly does speed my productivity greatly.  Past versions of Resharper have had some bad performance issue with the IDE but I have had no issues with the most recent version.

Comment: Well, I use Reshaper with Agent Smith add-in. In work fine. But if you open big solution with a big web site, the performance of IDE became dramatically slow. But thanks to Resharper 4.5 the performance is better than it was in previous release.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper definitely puts a demand on hardware resources, particularly when using site wide analysis on a large project. Having said that, the extent of the performance hit is highly dependent on the host machine. On my work laptop (32 bit XP, 3Gb RAM, 7200 RPM HDD, 2.2 GHz dual core) it suffers but on my home PC (64 bit Win 7, 8Gb RAM, 7200 RPM HDD, 2.9 GHz quad core) it flies and I barely notice the performance hit. That said, I still couldn’t live without it even on the lower specced hardware. The productivity gain still outweighs the downtime in waiting for slower processes.

Answer (score 0):

I user Refactor! all the time. Just the time it saves me to encapsulate private variables into properties is worth it in my opinion.

That being said... a lot of the "benefits" of these programs are negated if you program it correctly to begin with.

For example, if you already habitually use "WITH" statements properly, you probably do not need something to clean up your style.

However in corporate America (and elsewhere I am sure), coding practices are not always followed by everyone, and rework and modifications are always coming in, so usually you will end up needing them eventually.

I personally have not experienced any noticeable difference in performance with these type of tools.

Comment: How does using `With` statement (you mean VB, right?) alleviates the need to refactor, or "cleans up your style"?

Comment: Sorry meant that more figuratively. There are a multitude of of items that these programs help you to "refactor", that are more of code cleaning that you can handle by just coding it correctly in the first place. It is not like these will code it for you, so the cleaner you code, the less effective these tools are for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have Resharper, Resharper Scout and Team Explorer + TFS Power tools. My Visual Studio definitely feels a little sluggish comparing to barebones, but if you want superspeed over features why not work in Notepad? For me, Resharper is definitely worth the viscosity.