# Telerik RadControls + JetBrains Resharper = VERY SLOW, Can anyone help?

Tags: ide, resharper, telerik

Anyone know of a way to speed up the Visual Studio IDE when you have Telerik RadControls (either windows or web) and JetBrains ReSharper installed?  If I disable ReSharper it runs rocking fast, but I love ReSharper a bit too much to drop it.  I know it would perform better without the RadControls.  Anyone know a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me this is the same.

I'm Working with a Dell XPS 4gb Ram Quad Core Extreme Stripped disks...
And I also had that problem with telerik controls (mainly aspx - winform not so much).

Anyhow - I had to do a project using a different suite of web controls - and it was as bad as with telerik - or even worse...

What I found (maybe it helps a bit):

a.) Switching to design view slows down the things a lot
--so after doing this I restart VS

b.) Small Solutions (Projects) help also (like mika wrote) --if possible split your solution to several projects (some class libs instead of one big thing)

c.) Use as litte VS addins as possible --I used some nice tools - but at the moment most of them are turned of, because I made the expirience that the things are better the less addins I use.

d.) Run special "resharping sessions" -- what I mean is: turn resharper off, do you normal coding - and from time to time turn it on and "resharp" your code.

This problem (as well as some others) is well knwon (I guess) and I would say that neither resharper (although this tool seems to be somewhat special) nor telerik are gulty.

It is VS which makes the problems - and I did a lot of searches about solutions - but finally I found nothing which really helps.

Notice: I work on a pretty large project at the moment - and the use of respharper is almost impossible. I turned it off - instead I have a lot of nice snippets and macros which help me to do some of the common things.

Conclusion: if telerik + reshaper is to slow for you I guess you have to decide which helps you more :)

I use the telerik controls (ASPX, WPF and Silverlight) in almost every project I make. These tools fasten the things so much - I simply "need them to survive"

Answer (score 2):

I switched from DevExpress CodeRush/Refactor! to Resharper (not by choice) and found the IDE became almost unusable.  I managed to persuade my boss to let me switch back (on my own personal licence) and now it's like walking back into the sunshine after months in a cold, damp cave.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that maybe you should consider switching to CodeRush and Refactor!

Answer (score 0):

This is not much help, but at least the issue is not on your machine only...

Try to work with **small solutions**. In my machine this means solutions with less than 100k lines of code. Background compilation makes IDE sluggish with large solutions. VB has background compilation on by default, and even without add-ins it gets slower as the solution size grows.

I haven't been able to use ReSharper or CodeRush/Refactor! with VB & RadControls with over 100k line solutions, things just slow down too much. I'm using a Core 2 Duo, 2.4GHz, 4GB machine.

See also: [Visual Studio performance and add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268185/visual-studio-performance-and-add-ins)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Telerik`s forums:

We are incompatible with JetBrains Resharper indeed. We are competing for the same Visual Studio resources which could potentially create a ton of trouble if you run both of the add-ins together.  I doubt that anybody managed to run them together but if you know somebody that did that I'd be really interested in all the details.

So you have to disable Resharper to check out on JustCode. You could always re-enable it later, however, as long as one of them is disabled they coexist happily.

Kind regards,
Tsviatko
the Telerik team

And I am pretty sure you will be way better using only JustCode